# What is the standard idiom for implementing equals and hashCode in Scala?

Tags: scala, equals, hashcode

What is the standard idiom for implementing the `equals` and `hashCode` methods in Scala?

I know the preferred approach is discussed in *[Programming in Scala](http://www.artima.com/shop/programming_in_scala_2ed)*, but I don't currently have access to the book.

Comment: Here is free [1st edition Programming in Scala](http://www.artima.com/pins1ed/object-equality.html)

Comment: The advice provided at that link is outdated and now incorrect. Please see my "Answer" below for a current and correct implementation (as of 2.13). https://stackoverflow.com/a/56509518/501113

Answer (score 20, accepted):

There's a free 1st edition of PinS that discuss this subject just as well. However, I think the *best* source is [this article](http://www.artima.com/lejava/articles/equality.html) by Odersky discussing equality in Java. The discussion in PinS is, iirc, an abbreviated version of this article.

Comment: Interestingly, at the end of the article there is a note suggesting the article was based off the Object Equality chapter in PinS. Something the book has which the article does not is [a summary of the steps to go through when writing an equals method](http://www.artima.com/pins1ed/object-equality.html#28.4). Thus, I tend to favor the book's version. It is nice to see the same material in both Java and Scala.

Comment: It would be great to include the relevant part of the article here. Plus, it deals with Java, not Scala. (Although of course many of the concerns are the same.)

Comment: @Michael Please see my answer which references, reimplements, and corrects the details from the article. https://stackoverflow.com/a/56509518/501113

Answer (score 13):

After doing quite a bit of research, I couldn't find an answer with an essential and correct implementation of the `equals` and `hashCode` pattern for a Scala class (not a case class as that is automatically compiler generated and [should not be overridden](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11402564/501113)). I did find a [2.10 (stale) macro](https://index.scala-lang.org/technology16/scalaequals/scalaequals-core/1.2.1?target=_2.10) making a valiant attempt at solving this.

I ended up combining the patterns recommended in ["Effective Java, 2nd Edition" (by Joshua Bloch)](http://thefinestartist.com/effective-java/08) and in this article ["How to Write an Equality Method in Java" (by Martin Odersky, Lex Spoon, and Bill Venners)](https://www.artima.com/lejava/articles/equality.html), and have created a standard default pattern I now use to implement `equals` and `hashCode` for my Scala classes.

The primary goal of the `equals` pattern is to minimize the number of actual comparison's required to execute to get to a valid and definitive `true` or `false`.

Additionally, the `hashCode` method should ALWAYS be overridden and re-implemented when the `equals` method is overridden (again, see ["Effective Java, 2nd Edition" (by Joshua Bloch)](http://thefinestartist.com/effective-java/08)). Hence, my inclusion of the `hashCode` method "pattern" in the code below which also incorporates [critical advice](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9078957/501113) about [using `##` instead of `hashCode`](https://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/Any.html#():Int) in the actual implementation.

It is worth mentioning that each of `super.equals` and `super.hashCode` must be called only if an ancestor has already overridden it. If not, then it is imperative to NOT call `super.*` as the default implementation in `java.lang.Object` ([`equals` compares for the same class instance](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#equals(java.lang.Object)) and [`hashCode` most likely converts the memory address of the object into an integer)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10917772/501113), both of which will break the specified `equals` and `hashCode` contract for the now overridden methods.

```
class Person(val name: String, val age: Int) extends Equals {
  override def canEqual(that: Any): Boolean =
    that.isInstanceOf[Person]

  //Intentionally avoiding the call to super.equals because no ancestor has overridden equals (see note 7 below)
  override def equals(that: Any): Boolean =
    that match {
      case person: Person =>
        (     (this eq person)                     //optional, but highly recommended sans very specific knowledge about this exact class implementation
          ||  (     person.canEqual(this)          //optional only if this class is marked final
                &&  (hashCode == person.hashCode)  //optional, exceptionally execution efficient if hashCode is cached, at an obvious space inefficiency tradeoff
                &&  (     (name == person.name)
                      &&  (age == person.age)
                    )
              )
        )
      case _ =>
        false
    }

  //Intentionally avoiding the call to super.hashCode because no ancestor has overridden hashCode (see note 7 below)
  override def hashCode(): Int =
    31 * (
      name.##
    ) + age.##
}
```

The code has a number of nuances which are critically important:

1. Extending `scala.Equals` - Ensures the `equals` idiomatic pattern, which includes the `canEqual` method formalization, is being fully implemented. While extending it is technically optional, it remains highly recommended.
2. Same instance short circuit - Testing `(this eq person)` for `true` ensures no further (expensive) comparisons as it is literally the same instance. This test is required to be inside the pattern match as the `eq` method is available on `AnyRef`, not on `Any` (the type of `that`). And because `AnyRef` is an ancestor of `Person`, this technique is doing two simultaneous type validations by type validating the descendant, `Person`, which implies an automatic type validation of all its ancestors, including `AnyRef`, which is required for the `eq` check. While this test is technically optional, it remains highly recommended.
3. Check `that`'s `canEqual` - It's very easy to get this backwards which is INCORRECT. It is crucial the check of `canEqual` be executed on the `that` instance with `this` provided as the parameter. And while it might seem redundant to the pattern match (given we get to this line of code, `that` must be a `Person` instance), we must still make the method call as we cannot assume `that` is an equals-compatible descendant of `Person` (all descendants of `Person` will successfully pattern match as a `Person`). If the class is marked `final`, this test optional and may be safely removed. Otherwise, it is required.
4. Checking `hashCode` short circuit - While not sufficient nor required, if this `hashCode` test is `false`, it eliminates the need to perform all the value level checks (item 5). If this test is `true`, then a field by field check is actually required. This test is optional, and may be excluded if the hashCode value isn't cached *and* the total cost of the per-field equality checks is low enough.
5. Per-field equality checks - Even if the `hashCode` test is provided and succeeds, all of the field level values must still be checked. This is because, although it is highly improbable, [it remains possible for two different instances to generate the exact same `hashCode` value, and still not be actually equivalent at the field level](https://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/Any.html#hashCode():Int). The parent's `equals` must also be invoked to ensure any additional field's defined in ancestors are also tested.
6. Pattern match `case _ =>` - This is actually achieving two different effects. First, Scala pattern match guarantees a `null` is properly routed here so `null` doesn't have to appear anywhere within our pure Scala code. Secondly, the pattern match guarantees whatever `that` is, it isn't an instance of `Person` or one of its descendants.
7. When to call each of `super.equals` and `super.hashCode` is a bit tricky - If an ancestor has already overridden both (should never be either) of these, it is imperative you incorporate `super.*` in your own overridden implementations. And if an ancestor has not overridden both, then your overridden implementations must avoid invoking `super.*`. The `Person` code example above shows the case where there is no *ancestor* who has overridden both. So, calling each `super.*` method call would incorrectly fall all the way to the default `java.lang.Object.*` implementation which would invalidate the assumed combined contract for `equals` and `hashCode`.

This is the `super.equals` based code to use ONLY IF there is at least one ancestor who has explicitly overridden `equals` already.

```
override def equals(that: Any): Boolean =
  ...
    case person: Person =>
      ( ...
                //WARNING: including the next line ASSUMES at least one ancestor has already overridden equals; i.e. that this does not end up invoking java.lang.Object.equals
                &&  (     super.equals(person)     //incorporate checking ancestor(s)' fields
                      &&  (name == person.name)
                      &&  (age == person.age)
                )
            ...
      )
    ...
```

This is the `super.hashCode` based code to use ONLY IF there is at least one ancestor who has explicitly overridden `hashCode` already.

```
override def hashCode(): Int =
  31 * (
    31 * (
      //WARNING: including the next line ASSUMES at least one ancestor has already overridden hashCode; i.e. that this does not end up invoking java.lang.Object.hashCode
      super.hashCode  //incorporate adding ancestor(s)' hashCode (and thereby, their fields)
    ) + name.##
  ) + age.##
```

---

One final note: In my doing research for this, I couldn't believe how many erred implementations of this pattern exist. It is clearly still an area where it's difficult to get the details right:

1. [Programming in Scala, First Edition](https://www.artima.com/pins1ed/object-equality.html#28.4) - Missed 1, 2, and 4 above.
2. [Alvin Alexander's Scala Cookbook](https://alvinalexander.com/scala/how-to-define-equals-hashcode-methods-in-scala-object-equality) - Missed 1, 2, and 4.
3. [Code Examples for Programming in Scala](https://www.cs.helsinki.fi/u/wikla/OTS/Sisalto/examples/html/ch28.html) - Incorrectly uses `.hashCode` instead of `.##` on class fields when generating class's `hashCode` override and implementation. See Tree3.scala

Comment: Why wouldn't you just use a case class here?

Comment: Don't use .hashCode in the implementation of hashCode.  Use ##.  It's the equivalent of == and fixes issues of cooperative equality.

Comment: @Thilo Because the above example is a stripped down version of a much more complex (non-case) class which still needs to be used in the various Scala and Java collections.

Comment: @DaleWijnand Got it. I found a link where this is clarified on Stackoverflow and added it. https://stackoverflow.com/q/9068154/501113

Comment: @DaleWijnand Am I correctly deducing you are suggesting the `equals` code snippet of `(hashCode == person.hashCode)` should remain the same?

Comment: If something is too complex to be a case-class, but still needs to be treated as a "value object" (i.e. have equals, hashCode), it may be time to break out some pieces. Putting yourself in a situation where you have to manually write this mechanical (and as you point out, error-prone) code seems like you are not making full use of the language.

Comment: @chaotic3quilibrium yes

Comment: @Thilo I agree the Scala case class is awesome. However, I think you make way too many assumptions about the many and varied contexts within which a Scala software engineer must solve problems. It isn't my place to tell another software engineer they must use a case class to solve their problem. I don't and won't have enough context to be able to confidently assert the "correct" solution. The only assumption I am making is that _sometimes_ (and perhaps even rarely), someone will need to implement this pattern (including me), so having the pattern explicitly captured remains helpful.

Comment: @Thilo After having to edit this "Answer" numerous times to continue to converge on a full context answer, I'm beginning to value your specific advice quite a bit more now. I still contend that it is useful to capture this somewhere. However, implementing this has turned into dozens and dozens of unforeseen tangents. It makes me wonder why `scala.Equals` didn't include `hashCode` as a method given the clear and unequivocal assumption that if one overrides `equals`, one is required to also override `hashCode`.

Comment: So, I finally hit a use case where I had to use this pattern. IOW, I couldn't use a case class (never override equals/hashCode). Because one of the properties is an `Array`, `==` wasn't an option on the `Array` and required I implement as a class and provide the `equals` (which had to use `sameElements`) and `hashCode`. It is clearly an outlier. However, I was SO happy to come back to this answer and "remember" all the issues as I was implementing this.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, overriding `equals` and `hashCode` is a dauting task in both Java and Scala. I would recommend not to use `equals` at all, and instead use a type class (`Eq`/`Eql` etc.). It's more typesafe (compiler error when comparing unrelated types), easier to implement (no overriding and class checking) and more flexible (you can write type class instances separate from the data class). Dotty uses a concept of ["multiversal equality"](https://dotty.epfl.ch/docs/reference/contextual/multiversal-equality.html) which offers a choice between catching some obviously incorrect usages of `equals` and strict equality checking a la Haskell.

Comment: Excellent advice. I concur and STRONGLY advise anyone in this area to move to the type class solutions as much as is possible. Of course, the problem is if the class is being used in the Scala Collections. Those by default depend upon both the `equals` and `hashCode` methods from `java.lang.Object`.