# What is the difference between `##` and `hashCode`?

Tags: scala, hashcode

What is the difference between methods `##` and `hashCode`?

They seem to be outputting the same values no matter which class or `hashCode` overloading I use. Google doesn't help, either, as it cannot find symbol `##`.

Comment: `1.0 hashCode` v `1.0 ##` v `1 hashCode` v `1 ##` — http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/Any.html

Comment: A little offtopic, but you can search for such symbols using [SymbolHound](http://www.symbolhound.com/).

Comment: Ah ok. So, `1.hashCode` `==` `1.##`, and `1.2.hashCode` `==` `1.2.##`. The only thing that behaves differently is `1.0.hashCode` `!=` `1.0.##` (so `##` is better suited for comparing numbers).

Comment: From the Scala docs on Any "Equivalent to x.hashCode except for boxed numeric types. For numerics, it returns a hash value which is consistent with value equality: if two value type instances compare as true, then ## will produce the same hash value for each of them.".

Comment: @om-nom-nom, a little of topic, but thanks for the tip. That's awesome!

Answer (score 40, accepted):

"Subclasses" of `AnyVal` do not behave *properly* from a hashing perspective:

```
scala> 1.0.hashCode
res14: Int = 1072693248
```

Of course this is boxed to a call to:

```
scala> new java.lang.Double(1.0).hashCode
res16: Int = 1072693248
```

We might prefer it to be:

```
scala> new java.lang.Double(1.0).##
res17: Int = 1

scala> 1.0.##
res15: Int = 1
```

We should expect this given that the `int` 1 is also the `double` 1. Of course this issue does not arise in Java. Without it, we'd have this problem:

```
Set(1.0) contains 1 //compiles but is false
```

Luckily:

```
scala> Set(1.0) contains 1
res21: Boolean = true
```

Comment: So, when implementing both `equals` and `hashCode` for a particular class, I'm not sure how this translates into the best strategy. I am assuming the `hashCode` implementation should use `##`. However, should the `equals` implementation use `hashCode` or `##`? Here's the answer I provided on another thread which assumes that the `equals` implementation should use `hashCode` and the `hashCode` implementation should use `##`. Evaluation and feedback on this would be greatly appreciated. https://stackoverflow.com/a/56509518/501113

Answer (score 35):

`##` was introduced because `hashCode` is not consistent with the `==` operator in Scala. If `a == b` then `a.## == b.##` regardless of the type of a and b (if custom `hashCode` implementations are correct). The same is not true for `hashCode` as can be seen in the examples given by other posters.

Comment: So, when implementing both `equals` and `hashCode` for a particular class, I'm not sure how this translates into the best strategy. I am assuming the `hashCode` implementation should use `##`. However, should the `equals` implementation use `hashCode` or `##`? Here's the answer I provided on another thread which assumes that the `equals` implementation should use `hashCode` and the `hashCode` implementation should use `##`. Evaluation and feedback on this would be greatly appreciated. https://stackoverflow.com/a/56509518/501113

Answer (score 6):

Just want to add to the answers of other posters that although the ## method strives to keep the contract between equality and hash codes, it is apparently not good enough in some cases, like when you are comparing doubles and longs (scala 2.10.2):

```
> import java.lang._
import java.lang._

> val lng = Integer.MAX_VALUE.toLong + 1
lng: Long = 2147483648

> val dbl = Integer.MAX_VALUE.toDouble + 1
dbl: Double = 2.147483648E9

> lng == dbl
res65: Boolean = true

> lng.## == dbl.##
res66: Boolean = false

> (lng.##, lng.hashCode)
res67: (Int, Int) = (-2147483647,-2147483648)

> (dbl.##, dbl.hashCode)
res68: (Int, Int) = (-2147483648,1105199104)
```

Comment: Really? Is this a bug?

Comment: It clearly is as according to scaladoc for ## "... it returns a hash value which is consistent with value equality: if two value type instances compare as true, then ## will produce the same hash value for each of them..."

Comment: I just checked this in scala 2.11.7 and did not see the same behavior for `==` and `.## == .##`

Answer (score 3):

In addition to what everyone else said, I'd like to say that `##` is null-safe, because `null.##` returns  `0` whereas `null.hashCode` throws `NullPointerException`.

From scaladoc:

> Equivalent to x.hashCode except for boxed numeric types and null. For numerics, it returns a hash value which is consistent with value equality: if two value type instances compare as true, then ## will produce the same hash value for each of them. For null returns a hashcode where null.hashCode throws a NullPointerException.