# hashcode and ## result differ for Double,Float

Tags: scala

why ## of Double,Float result different from hashCode

Double example

```
scala> var x = 130d
x: Double = 130.0

scala> x.##
res24: Int = 130

scala> x.hashCode
res25: Int = 1080049664
```

Float

```
scala> var x = 130f
x: Float = 130.0

scala> x.##
res28: Int = 130

scala> x.hashCode
res29: Int = 1124204544
```

Integer Result Same value

```
scala> x.##
res30: Int = 130

scala> x.hashCode
res31: Int = 130
```

String result same value

```
scala> var x = "demo"
x: String = demo

 scala> x.##
 res32: Int = 3079651

 scala> x.hashCode
 res33: Int = 3079651
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9068154/what-is-the-difference-between-and-hashcode