# ## Operator in scala

Tags: scala, hashcode

What does `##` method mean in Scala. It is referenced in Scala's built-in hashCode method.

http://lampsvn.epfl.ch/trac/scala/browser/scala/branches/2.8.x/src/library/scala/runtime/ScalaRunTime.scala#L151

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9068154/what-is-the-difference-between-and-hashcode

Comment: Or read the [scaladoc](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.11.6/index.html#scala.Any@##():Int), even.