# Equality and Case Classes

Tags: scala, equals, case-class

I have:

```
sealed trait BEValue

case class BEByteString(val value: Array[Byte]) extends BEValue { 
  def equals(that: BEByteString): Boolean = this.value.deep == that.value.deep
  def ==(that: BEByteString) = this equals that
}

case class BEList(val value: List[BEValue]) extends BEValue

BEByteString("spam".getBytes) == BEByteString("spam".getBytes) //true

val l1 =  BEList(BEByteString("spam".getBytes):: Nil)
val l2 =  BEList(BEByteString("spam".getBytes):: Nil)

l1 == l2 // false. Why ?
```

Comment: You can omit the `val` keyword in case classes. It is added by default.

Comment: I just posted an answer on another question which is a more detailed answer to your question. It is crucial for instances of your (case) class to correctly implement both equals and hashCode to properly behave within the Scala collections library. Or suffer unexpected failures. stackoverflow.com/a/56509518/501113

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should not create your own `==` method. In scala `==` method is implemented using `equals`.

You should use `override` keyword to override `equals` method.

```
case class BEByteString(val value: Array[Byte]) extends BEValue { 
  override def equals(that: BEByteString): Boolean = this.value.deep == that.value.deep
}
// <console>:11: error: method equals overrides nothing
//          override def equals(that: BEByteString): Boolean = this.value.deep == that.value.deep
//                       ^
```

You have created a new `equals` method. And your new `==` method is implemented using your new `equals` method. But case class equals is implemented using `Any#equals` method for parameters.

`Any#equals` method signature is `def equals(that: Any): Boolean`

```
case class BEByteString(val value: Array[Byte]) extends BEValue { 
  override def equals(that: Any): Boolean = that match {
    case BEByteString(thatValue) => thatValue.deep == this.value.deep
    case _ => false
  }
}

l1 == l2 
// Boolean = true
```

Note that you could use `IndexedSeq[Byte]` instead of `Array[Byte]`. In this case you could use a default `equals` implementation. It also makes your `BEByteString` class immutable: with `Array[Byte]` one can change a content of `value`.

Comment: Just a quick tip: `java.util.Arrays.equals(this.value, that.value)` is probably faster than `this.value.deep == that.value.deep`

Comment: And I thought Scala was a typesafe langauge ;)

Comment: @Jamil: It's typesafe, but it also allows method overloading.

Comment: I am talking about `that: Any`. Which is to say that l1.equals("2") is not a compile time error but rather an isInstanceOf/asInstanceOf cast.

Comment: @Jamil: `that: Any` in `equals` is inherited from `java`. If you want to get a typesafe equality take a look at [scalaz/Equal](http://eed3si9n.com/learning-scalaz/Equal.html).

Comment: @Jamil: Note that you could use `IndexedSeq[Byte]` instead of `Array[Byte]`. In this case you could use a default `equals` implementation.

Comment: additionally, per http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7370925/what-is-the-standard-idiom-for-implementing-equals-and-hashcode-in-scala , you'll want to define `hashCode` as well. see http://www.artima.com/lejava/articles/equality.html