# canEqual() in the scala.Equals trait

Tags: scala, internals, scala-2.11

From the source code `scala/Equals.scala` ([here](https://github.com/scala/scala/blob/2.11.x/src/library/scala/Equals.scala)):

```
package scala
trait Equals extends scala.Any {
  def canEqual(that: scala.Any): scala.Boolean
  def equals(that: scala.Any): scala.Boolean
}
```

In the documentation, it says:

> A method that should be called from every well-designed equals method that is open to be overridden in a subclass.

I randomly picked a class which extends `scala.Equals` and which is simple enough to understand. I picked `scala.Tuple2[+T1, +T2]`, which extends the trait `scala.Product[T1, T2]`, which in turn extends the trait `scala.Product`, which in turn extends the trait `scala.Equals`.

Unfortunately, it seems that because `scala.Tuple2` is a *case class*, the `canEqual()` and `equals()` methods are automatically generated and therefore could not be found in the source code `scala/Tuple2.scala` ([here](https://github.com/scala/scala/blob/2.11.x/src/library/scala/Tuple2.scala)).

My questions are:

- When is it a good time to extend the trait `scala.Equals`?
- How should `canEqual()` be implemented?
- What are the best practices (or boilerplate) to use `canEqual()` in `equals()`?

Thanks in advance!

PS: In case if it matters, I'm using Scala 2.11.7.

Comment: I just posted an answer on another question which answers the second and third of your questions. And it appears no one has answered your first question. I would say the answer to your third question is: Always extend `scala.Equals` on any class (but not a case class) where you are implementing any of `equals`, `canEquals`, or `hashCode`. It is crucial for instances of your class to properly behave within the Scala collections library. IOW, you must get your implementations correct in this area or suffer unexpected, and like silent, failures. http://stackoverflow.com/a/56509518/501113

Answer (score 20, accepted):

The `canEquals` method is used to cover the expectation that `equals` should be symmetric - that is, if (and only if) `a.equals(b)` is true, then `b.equals(a)` should also be true. Problems with this can arise when comparing an instance of a class with an instance of a sub-class. Eg.

```
class Animal(numLegs: Int, isCarnivore: Boolean) {
  def equals(other: Any) = other match {
    case that: Animal => 
      this.numLegs == that.numLegs && 
      this.isCarnivore == that.isCarnivore
    case _ => false
  }
}

class Dog(numLegs: Int, isCarnivore: Boolean, breed: String) extends Animal(numLegs, isCarnivore) {
  def equals(other: Any) = other match {
    case that: Dog => 
      this.numLegs == that.numLegs && 
      this.isCarnivore == that.isCarnivore &&
      this.breed == that.breed
    case _ => false
  }
}

val cecil = new Animal(4, true)
val bruce = new Dog(4, true, "Boxer")
cecil.equals(bruce) // true
bruce.equals(cecil) // false - cecil isn't a Dog!
```

To fix this, ensure the two entities are of the same (sub-)type using `canEqual` in the definition of `equals`:

```
class Animal(numLegs: Int, isCarnivore: Boolean) {
  def canEqual(other: Any) = other.isInstanceOf[Animal]
  def equals(other: Any) = other match {
    case that: Animal => 
      that.canEqual(this) &&
      this.numLegs == that.numLegs && 
      this.isCarnivore == that.isCarnivore
    case _ => false
  }
}

class Dog(numLegs: Int, isCarnivore: Boolean, breed: String) extends Animal(numLegs, isCarnivore) {
  def canEqual(other: Any) = other.isInstanceOf[Dog]
  def equals(other: Any) = other match {
    case that: Dog => 
      that.canEqual(this) &&
      this.numLegs == that.numLegs && 
      this.isCarnivore == that.isCarnivore &&
      this.breed == that.breed
    case _ => false
  }
}

val cecil = new Animal(4, true)
val bruce = new Dog(4, true, "Boxer")
cecil.equals(bruce) // false - call to bruce.canEqual(cecil) returns false
bruce.equals(cecil) // false
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I think the trick is `that.canEqual(this)` instead of `this.canEqual(that)`, which does the check "in an opposite way" to ensure the validness of `equals()`. Do you know whether the generated case class version follows the same pattern as you have shown here? Thanks!

Comment: @SiuChingPong-AsukaKenji- I believe it does, but I don't know for sure.

Comment: This answer is incomplete, bordering on incorrect. When overriding `equals`, it is required `hashCode` also be overridden. There are many other nuances to implementing `equals`, `canEquals`, and `hashCode` which I detail here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/56509518/501113